# How can I remove or disable some initialization from super class?

Tags: swift

I want disable or remove some initialization from my super class, here my test codes:

```
class MyA {
    
    init() {
        
    }
    
    init(value: String) {
        
    }
    
    init(value2: String) {
        
    }
}


class MyB: MyA {
    
}
```

As you can see MyA has 3 initialization and MyB has the same because it is sub class, so I want remove 2 of this 3 initialization in MyB class, I want MyB just be initialize with init(), how can i do this? and the other 2 way be unavailable for sub class.

Comment: according to the docs:  https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html  `Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses don’t inherit their superclass initializers by default. `

Comment: I think subclass in question in swift inherit their superclass initializers by default. Not sure what you want to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

As such, define a designated initializer.

```swift
class MyB: MyA {
  override init() {
    super.init()
  }
}
```